# mpi4py scatter and gather with large numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mpi4py

I am trying to parallelise some operations on a large numpy array using mpi4py. I am currently using `numpy.array_split` to divide the array into chunks, followed by `com.scatter` to send the array to different cores and then `comm.gather` to collect the resulting arrays. A minimal (not) working example is below:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    test = np.random.rand(411,48,52,40)
    test_chunks = np.array_split(test,size,axis=0)

else:
    test_chunks = None

test_chunk = comm.scatter(test_chunks,root=0)
output_chunk = np.zeros([np.shape(test_chunk)[0],128,128,128])

for i in range(0,np.shape(test_chunk)[0],1):
    print(i)
    output_chunk[i,0:48,0:52,0:40] = test_chunk[i]

outputData = comm.gather(output_chunk,root=0)


if rank == 0:
    outputData = np.concatenate(outputData,axis = 0)
```

Running this gives me the error:

```
  File "test_4d.py", line 23, in <module>
    outputData = comm.gather(output_chunk,root=0)
  File "Comm.pyx", line 869, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.gather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:73266)
  File "pickled.pxi", line 614, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_gather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:33592)
  File "pickled.pxi", line 146, in mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle.allocv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:28517)
  File "pickled.pxi", line 95, in mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle.alloc (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:27832)
SystemError: Negative size passed to PyString_FromStringAndSize
```

This error seems to result from the large size of the numpy arrays being collected by gather; since scatter and gather send the arrays as a list of arrays, it appears easy to exceed the list size. One suggestion I have come across is to use comm.Scatter and comm.Gather. However, I am struggling to find clear documentation for these functions and so far have been unable to successfully implement them. For example:

replacing

`outputData = comm.gather(output_chunk,root=0)`

with the line

`outputData=comm.Gather(sendbuf[test_chunks,MPI.DOUBLE],recvbuf=output_chunk,MPI.DOUBLE],root=0)`

gives the error:

```
  File "Comm.pyx", line 415, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Gather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:66916)
  File "message.pxi", line 426, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_gather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:23559)
  File "message.pxi", line 355, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22959)
  File "message.pxi", line 111, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:20516)
  File "message.pxi", line 51, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:19644)
  File "asbuffer.pxi", line 108, in mpi4py.MPI.getbuffer (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:6757)
  File "asbuffer.pxi", line 50, in mpi4py.MPI.PyObject_GetBufferEx (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:6093)
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

or with the line:

```
outputData = comm.Gather(sendbuf=test_chunks, recvbuf=output_chunk,root=0)
```

gives the error:

```
  File "test_4d_2.py", line 24, in <module>
    outputData = comm.Gather(sendbuf=test_chunks, recvbuf=output_chunk,root=0)
  File "Comm.pyx", line 415, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Gather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:66916)
  File "message.pxi", line 426, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_gather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:23559)
  File "message.pxi", line 355, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22959)
  File "message.pxi", line 111, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:20516)
  File "message.pxi", line 60, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:19747)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Furthermore, the input matrix, `test` may also increase in size, which could cause similar problems for `comm.scatter`. Aside from the problems I already have with `comm.Gather`, I am not sure how to set up `comm.Scatter`, since `recvbuf` is defined based on the size of `test_chunk`, which is the output of `comm.scatter`, so hence I can't specify `recvbuf` within `comm.Scatter`.

Comment: I think the problem maybe that `output_chunk` doesnt actually have anything in it as you are setting `test_chunks = none` in every node except the root node. Then in each node you are scattering it. At least thats how your code reads to me.

Comment: Sorry went through it again ignore the last sentences of my last comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's that simple. My understanding (which may be wrong) is that all the non-root nodes need to have already setup the variables, arrays etc. that are going to be passed to them. Hence setting `test_chunks = None`. I've tested the above MWE with a 3d input array `np.random.rand(411,48,52)` and a 3d output array `np.zeros(411,128,128)` and the code runs fine, so it's definitely an issue that only appears with larger matrix sizes

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use `comm.Scatterv` and `comm.Gatherv` which send and receive the data as a block of memory, rather than a list of numpy arrays, getting around the data size issue. `comm.Scatterv` and `comm.Gatherv` assume a block of data in C-order (row-major) in memory and it is necessary to specify two vectors, `sendcounts` and `displacements`. `Sendcounts` gives the integer value (index) for the positions at which to split the input data (i.e. the starting point of each vector to send to a given core), while `displacements` gives the length of that vector. Hence it is possible to vary the amount of data sent to each core. More details can be found here: http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/collectiveCom.html

An example using `comm.Scatterv` and `comm.Gatherv` for a 2D matrix is given here:
[Along what axis does mpi4py Scatterv function split a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025188/along-what-axis-does-mpi4py-scatterv-function-split-a-numpy-array/36082684#36082684)