# Along what axis does mpi4py Scatterv function split a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mpi4py

I have the following MWE using `comm.Scatterv` and `comm.Gatherv` to distribute a 4D array across a given number of cores (`size`)

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    test = np.random.rand(411,48,52,40) #Create array of random numbers
    outputData = np.zeros(np.shape(test))
    split = np.array_split(test,size,axis = 0) #Split input array by the number of available cores

    split_sizes = []

    for i in range(0,len(split),1):
        split_sizes = np.append(split_sizes, len(split[i]))

    displacements = np.insert(np.cumsum(split_sizes),0,0)[0:-1]

    plt.imshow(test[0,0,:,:])
    plt.show()

else:
#Create variables on other cores
    split_sizes = None
    displacements = None
    split = None
    test = None
    outputData = None

#Broadcast variables to other cores
test = comm.bcast(test, root = 0)
split = comm.bcast(split, root=0) 
split_sizes = comm.bcast(split_sizes, root = 0)
displacements = comm.bcast(displacements, root = 0)

output_chunk = np.zeros(np.shape(split[rank])) #Create array to receive subset of data on each core, where rank specifies the core
print("Rank %d with output_chunk shape %s" %(rank,output_chunk.shape))

comm.Scatterv([test,split_sizes, displacements,MPI.DOUBLE],output_chunk,root=0) #Scatter data from test across cores and receive in output_chunk

output = output_chunk

plt.imshow(output_chunk[0,0,:,:])
plt.show()

print("Output shape %s for rank %d" %(output.shape,rank))

comm.Barrier()

comm.Gatherv(output,[outputData,split_sizes,displacements,MPI.DOUBLE], root=0) #Gather output data together

if rank == 0:
    print("Final data shape %s" %(outputData.shape,))
    plt.imshow(outputData[0,0,:,:])
    plt.show()
```

This creates a 4D array of random numbers and in principle should divide it across `size` cores before recombining. I expected `Scatterv` to divide along axis 0 (length 411) according to the starting integers and displacements in the vectors `split_sizes` and `displacements`. However, I get an error when recombining with `Gatherv` (`mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated`) and the plot of output_chunk on each core shows that most of the input data has been lost, so it appears that the split has not occurred along the first axis.

My questions are: Why doesn't the split occur along the first axis, how do I know which axis the split occurs along, and is it possible to change/specify which axis this occurs along?

Comment: `comm.Scatterv` probably knows nothing about `numpy` array, shape, dimensions or strides.  At best it can treat `test` as a block of memory.  In fact it may only be getting the pointer to array object, not its data buffer.  Does this code work with a 1d array?  Or `test.flatten()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`comm.Scatterv` and `comm.Gatherv` do not know anything about the numpy array dimensions. They just see the `sendbuf` as a block of memory. Therefore it is necessary to take this into account when specifying the `sendcounts` and `displacements` (see http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/collectiveCom.html for details). The assumption is also that the data is laid out in C-style (row major) in memory.

An example for a 2D matrix is given below. The key parts of this code are to set `split_sizes_input`/`split_sizes_output` and `displacements_input`/`displacements_output` correctly. The code takes the second dimension size into account to specify the correct divisions in the memory block:

```
split_sizes_input = split_sizes*512
```

For higher dimensions, this line would be changed to:

```
split_sizes_input = split_sizes*indirect_dimension_sizes
```

where

`indirect_dimension_sizes = npts2*npts3*npts4*....*nptsN`

and likewise for `split_sizes_output`.

The code creates a 2D array with the numbers 1 to 512 incrementing across one dimension. It is easy to see from the plots if the data has been split and recombined correctly.

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    test = np.arange(0,512,dtype='float64')
    test = np.tile(test,[256,1]) #Create 2D input array. Numbers 1 to 512 increment across dimension 2.
    outputData = np.zeros([256,512]) #Create output array of same size
    split = np.array_split(test,size,axis = 0) #Split input array by the number of available cores

    split_sizes = []

    for i in range(0,len(split),1):
        split_sizes = np.append(split_sizes, len(split[i]))

    split_sizes_input = split_sizes*512
    displacements_input = np.insert(np.cumsum(split_sizes_input),0,0)[0:-1]

    split_sizes_output = split_sizes*512
    displacements_output = np.insert(np.cumsum(split_sizes_output),0,0)[0:-1]


    print("Input data split into vectors of sizes %s" %split_sizes_input)
    print("Input data split with displacements of %s" %displacements_input)

    plt.imshow(test)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Input data')
    plt.show()

else:
#Create variables on other cores
    split_sizes_input = None
    displacements_input = None
    split_sizes_output = None
    displacements_output = None
    split = None
    test = None
    outputData = None

split = comm.bcast(split, root=0) #Broadcast split array to other cores
split_sizes = comm.bcast(split_sizes_input, root = 0)
displacements = comm.bcast(displacements_input, root = 0)
split_sizes_output = comm.bcast(split_sizes_output, root = 0)
displacements_output = comm.bcast(displacements_output, root = 0)

output_chunk = np.zeros(np.shape(split[rank])) #Create array to receive subset of data on each core, where rank specifies the core
print("Rank %d with output_chunk shape %s" %(rank,output_chunk.shape))
comm.Scatterv([test,split_sizes_input, displacements_input,MPI.DOUBLE],output_chunk,root=0)

output = np.zeros([len(output_chunk),512]) #Create output array on each core

for i in range(0,np.shape(output_chunk)[0],1):
    output[i,0:512] = output_chunk[i]

plt.imshow(output)
plt.title("Output shape %s for rank %d" %(output.shape,rank))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

print("Output shape %s for rank %d" %(output.shape,rank))

comm.Barrier()

comm.Gatherv(output,[outputData,split_sizes_output,displacements_output,MPI.DOUBLE], root=0) #Gather output data together



if rank == 0:
    outputData = outputData[0:len(test),:]
    print("Final data shape %s" %(outputData.shape,))
    plt.imshow(outputData)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
    print(outputData)
```